# How to build HP LinkReader on Android

Tags: android, build.gradle

HP [LinkReader](https://mylinks.linkcreationstudio.com/overview) is a technology to put a Digital Watermark something like a QR Code that hidden in an image. When scanned, your watermark will launch a digital experience.

But nothing works, even its most basic example has problems to build, someone has already used it? Someone knows how to build a project with linkreader as a dependence?

Comment: Note: just because a Java library exists, does not mean it can be used in Android

Comment: @cricket_007 if you access the link that I put on the post, you will see that the module is developed to Android. Please read about LinkReader.

Comment: I did look, but I did not see how to add to an existing Android application